# ASP.NET MVC 4 Update Foreign key Table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two tables **Project** and **Tasks** in my db. **One project** may have **several tasks**, so it has tasks column where task ids are inserted. When new project is created, **tasks** column will be empty, it is nullable. However, when  new task is created, I want to get Task Id and modify Project table by adding newly created task id to tasks column. How can I do this in MVC 4?

Comment: I think you have a design problem.  If a `Project` can have many `Tasks` then the `Project` table should be unaware of the `Tasks`.  Each `Task` should have a `ProjectId` field that stores the `ProjectId` of it's associated `Project`.

Comment: Of course, Task Table has column named Project_ID, However when I create new task with ID=7 for project named "My project" for example, and when I see the Project table, under the column Project_Task its 0 instead of task ID 7.

Comment: The `Project` table should not have any sort of `Task` column.  If you want to see what `Tasks` are associated with a `Project`, you need to do a `JOIN` between the two tables on `ProjectId` (from the `Tasks` table) equal to the `ProjectId` from the `Projects` table.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you go with [Entity Framework - Code First](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) you can always take this approach, where a Project has many Tasks. I have created the Models for you

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProjectTask> ProjectTasks { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectTask
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int TaskId { get; set; }

    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProjectTask> ProjectTasks { get; set; }
}
```

Now, depending on your setup (Repositories, Context etc) you can just create your new tasks as you feel free, and then when ready, retrieve a Project and add to it like so.

```
var task = new Task() {Description = "My new task"};
Project project = ProjectRepository.FirstOrDefault();
if (project != null)
{
    project.ProjectTasks.Add(new ProjectTask(){Task = task});
    ProjectRepository.SaveChanges();
}
```

If this sounds like what you are going for I have attached some reading on setting up the Repository pattern in Entity Framework

**Further Reading**

[Implementing the Repository Pattern in EF](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

[Using Repository Pattern in EF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2013/08/23/using-repository-pattern-in-entity-framework.aspx)